# PhpStorm Xdebug how do I configure path mapping for full folder

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have this setup that one plugin in my project is symlinked to a different folder on my local machine.

Something like this:

```
/Sites/MyWebProject <-- contains application and PhpStorm project
/MyPlugins/MyCustomPlugin <-- contains my custom plugin that I am working on.
/Sites/MyWebProject/plugins/MyCustomPlugin --> symlinked to: /MyPlugins/MyCustomPlugin
```

Now when I run Xdebug and add a breakpoint PhpStorm will open the symlinked file. Then I can add a 'path mapping' and this file will be recognised as expected.

My issue is that I want to setup the 'path mapping' for the whole directory. And not on a 'per-file' base.

Is this possible?

Comment: So .... go to `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers` (that's where path mapping is set) and do that for a folder and not not individual file.

Comment: It's thats simple! Thanks LazyOne